# mysqlnd mysql_connect takes ages to connect

Tags: php, mysql

I'm deploying a new php project on a Windows based host and the big problem is, that mysql_connect takes literally ~1 second to connect to the mysql server on localhost each time. What the heck could be the problem?

PHPINFO says:

`Client API version     mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $`

No matter, what I try - PDO, mysqli or plain old mysql_connect - the connect time remains the same. What I noticed tho, that every mysql plugin (PDO, mysqli, mysql_connect) shows the same mysqlnd revision. Shall I ask the admin to nuke mysqlnd or this can be tuned somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be taking a while to resolve `localhost` - try connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead.